# Error while installing apps from WSO2 app manager

Tags: wso2, app-manager, wso2-iot

I am trying to install apps using wso2 app manager, but its not actually getting installed on my device.  I am attaching the log below

[image: error log]

Comment: is it only app manager? if it is you have to install WSO2 MDM(EMM) as well. otherwise you can't install app on your device.

Answer (score 1):

You can install apps on your device with APP Manager(APPM) and Enterprise Mobility Manager(EMM)combination. Follow below steps to integrate those two products and install apps on your device through app manager. These steps were extracted from [here](http://lakitechtips.blogspot.com/2016/04/wso2-app-manager-and-wso2-mobile-device.html)

There are two separate cases for APPM and EMM integration

1. APPM and EMM on a single JVM. ex : EMM standalone pack.
2. APPM and EMM on separate JVMs. ex : clustered scenario

For the first case, EMM standalone vanilla pack should work without changing any configuration.

For the second case, There are some configurations which should be done. Follow the below steps to configure APPM and EMM on a separate JVMs.

1. If you run APPM and EMM on same machine change the port offset of one pack. Let's change the port offset of APPM pack.

i) Change the port offset of carbon.xml to 10 which is in /repository/conf directory.
ii) Since APPM default authentication mechanism is SAML SSO change the port of IdentityProviderUrl also in app-manager.xml

```
    <!-- URL of the IDP use for SSO -->
    <IdentityProviderUrl>https://localhost:9453/samlsso</IdentityProviderUrl>

    <Configurators>
        <Configurator>
            <name>wso2is</name>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            <providerClass>org.wso2.carbon.appmgt.impl.idp.sso.configurator.IS500SAMLSSOConfigurator</providerClass>
            <parameters>
                <providerURL>https://localhost:9453</providerURL>
                <username>admin</username>
                <password>admin</password>
            </parameters>
        </Configurator>
    </Configurators>

</SSOConfiguration>
```

iii) Change the port offset to 9453 for all the ports found in sso-idp-config.xml which is located in /repository/conf/identity directory.

Now setting port offset is done.

2. Now create a mobile app by going to App Manager publisher. publish it and it will be available in APPM store.
3. Create an OAuth application in EMM by following article How to map existing oauth apps in wso2.
4. Open the app-manager.xml in APPM and find for a configuration called MobileAppsConfiguration. change ActiveMDM property to WSO2MDM.

ex: WSO2MDM

Change the MDM properties named as WSO2MDM as follows. Change the port to EMM port of ServerURL and TokenApiURL. Here client key and client secret is which returned from EMM when OAuth application is created.

```
<MDM name="WSO2MDM" bundle="org.wso2.carbon.appmgt.mdm.restconnector">
                <Property name="ImageURL">/store/extensions/assets/mobileapp/resources/models/%s.png</Property>
                <Property name="ServerURL">https://localhost:9453/mdm-admin</Property>
                <Property name="TokenApiURL">https://localhost:9453/oauth2/token</Property>
                <Property name="ClientKey">veQtMV1aH1iX0AFWQckJLiooTxUa</Property>
                <Property name="ClientSecret">cFGPUbV11yf9WgsL18d1Oga6JR0a</Property>
                <Property name="AuthUser">admin</Property>
                <Property name="AuthPass">admin</Property>
            </MDM>
```

5. Enroll your device in MDM.
6. Now you can install apps using app manager store to devices enrolled in EMM.